# Determinant of block matrix with A size 1x1

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have the following block matrix with dimensions

$ \begin{bmatrix}
    A       & B\\
    C       & D 
\end{bmatrix} == \begin{bmatrix}
    (1\times1)       & (1\times n)\\
    (n\times1)       & (n\times n) 
\end{bmatrix}$

I'm trying to compute the determinant with the following formula

$Det[A]Det[D-CA^{-1}B]$

which is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) on Wikipedia.

So, for my question. Since "A" is given as a 1x1 in my problem, would that mean that my equation for the determinant would reduce to

$Det[AD-CB]$

I will note that the inverse of "A" does exist. If it didn't, obviously this entire approach is wrong. I'm just not sure I can distribute $Det[A]$ into $Det[D-CA^{-1}B]$ as freely as I'd like to?

Comment: The answer is Yes!

Comment: @mike Friedrich says "No"?

Comment: @mike: Try some simple examples. Here is one: $\left\begin{matrix}2 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$. I don't see why the system doesn't take this one.

Comment: Sorry. I did not pay attention to the scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $A = a$ is a number. So you have for your block matrix $X$ (if you applied the Wiki formula correctly):
$$
Det[X] = Det[A]Det[D-CA^{-1}B] = aDet[D-Ca^{-1}B] = aDet[a^{-1}(AD-CB)] = aa^{-n}Det[AD-CB] = a^{1-n}Det[AD-CB].
$$

Comment: Wow...good thing I asked. Just to clarify. What is $a^{-n}$

Comment: $a^{-n} = 1/a^n$. I recall that $a$ is a number. BTW: The block in the upper right is 1xn and not nx1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it in the question. I'm still a bit confused by your answer with $a^{-n}$. Wouldn't "n" just be one? Hence $aa^{-1}=1$ and the it does reduce to $Det[AD-CB]$?

Comment: No. It is YOUR $n$. Namely the size of the matrix $D$. Note that $Det$ is not linear. For example, $Det(2I) = Det\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{matrix}\right) = 4 = 2^2Det(I)\neq 2Det(I)$, where $I$ is the 2x2 identity matrix. In general, you have $Det(tA) = t^nDet(A)$, where $n$ is the size of $A$.

Comment: O...OK...sorry. I didn't catch that. So "n" is from the dimension of D. Again, just to clarify...it is just "n" and not "nxn"? In other words, it is the number of columns of D (where D is square).

Comment: When you say "size", I just want to be clear that it's "n" and not "nxn". And that's with respect to the D-block

Comment: It is the number of columns of $D$ = the number of rows of $D$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36152/discussion-between-thatsrightjack-and-friedrich-philipp).