# Operators applied to determinant of block matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I would like to follow up on one of my [previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669790/determinant-of-block-matrix-with-a-size-1x1), where I have the following block matrix with dimensions

$ [M] := \begin{bmatrix}
    A       & B\\
    C       & D 
\end{bmatrix} := \begin{bmatrix}
    (1\times1)       & (1\times n)\\
    (n\times1)       & (n\times n) 
\end{bmatrix}$

To calculate the determinant, I can use the following formula (see [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669790/determinant-of-block-matrix-with-a-size-1x1) for clarification)

$Det[M] = a^{1-n}Det[aD-CB]$ where "a" is a scalar

My question is, if I have an operator acting on the determinant,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}Det[M] = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(a^{1-n}Det[aD-CB])$

do the following properties hold when applied with the formula...

- product rule

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}Det[M] = a^{1-n}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(Det[aD-CB])+Det[aD-CB]\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(a^{1-n})$

- if so, in the first term on the right hand side, can I distribute the operator inside the expression

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(Det[aD-CB])=Det[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(aD)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(CB)]$

I'm just not sure how to go about solving

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}Det[M] = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(a^{1-n}Det[aD-CB])$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $AD$ is a very bad one ($AD$ is not a matrix product). Let $A=a$.

It remains to calculate $(\det(aD-CB))'=\det(aD-CB)trace((aD-CB)'(aD-CB)^{-1})$

$=\det(aD-CB)trace((a'D+aD'-C'B-CB')(aD-CB)^{-1})$.

Comment: Can you tell me where you got this formula so I can reference it for further insight? Also if you have any references of examples it would be helpful as well.

Comment: OK...I was able to cross reference that formula in the https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: Just to clarify...is step one to still apply the product rule? You kindly showed the formula for the time derivative of $Det(aD-CB)$, which is obviously the most difficult part, but I just want to be sure I get the big picture. Basically is the equation shown above under "product rule" correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.